# How to grouping array of data by its category in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my data:

```
pets: [{id: 1, name: Susi, species: dog, gender: female},{id: 2, name: Xixi, species: dog, gender: female},{id: 3, name: Boss, species: rabbit, gender: male},{id: 4, name: Bunny, species: rabbit, gender: male},{id: 5, name: kitty, species: cat, gender: female},{id: 6, name: Garfield, species: cat, gender: male}]
```

How can I transform this data to grouping each pet according to its species and gender like like this:

```
data: [{species: dog, genders: [{gender: male, pets: [{id: 1, name: Susi, species: dog, gender: female},]}, {gender: female, pets: [{id: 2, name: Xixi, species: dog, gender: female},]}, ]},{species: cat, genders: [{gender: male, pets: [{id: 6, name: Garfield, species: cat, gender: male}]},{gender: female, pets: [{id:5, name: kitty, species: cat, gender: female},]},]},{species: rabbit,genders: [{gender: male, pets: [{id: 3, name: Boss, species: rabbit, gender: male},{id: 4, name: Bunny, species: rabbit, gender: male},]},{gender: female, pets: []},]}]
```

My code is:

```
const species = pets.reduce((acc, curr) => {
let item = acc.find(
  (item) =>
    item.spesies === curr.species || item.gender === curr.gender
);

if (item) {
  item.genders.push({
    gender: curr.gender,
    pets: [
     {
       id: acc.id,
       name: curr.name
     }
    ]
  });
} else {
  acc.push({
    species: curr.species
    genders: [
    gender: curr.gender,
    pets: [
     {
       id: acc.id,
       name: curr.name
     }
    ]
  ]
  });
}
return acc;}, []);
```

the result from my code is:

```
data: [{species: dog, genders: [{gender: female, pets: Array(1)},{gender: female, pets: Array(1)},]},species: cat, genders: [{gender: male, pets: Array(1)},{gender: female, pets: Array(1)},]},{species: rabbit, genders: [{gender: male, pets: Array(1)},{gender: male, pets: Array(1)}]}]
```

I expect the final result is like  the second array above.
Does any one know how to do this better and explaining what I'm missing. Thanks!!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) (If you provide your sample input data in code form, it is much easier for people to work with, than if they had to type it off of your screenshot ...)

Comment: Fix a few typos and your code works. No comma here: `species: curr.species`, as in: `species: curr.species,`. Need an object here: `genders: [`, as in `genders: [{`. And of course match the curly braces on the other end of the array. Use `curr` not `acc` here: `id: acc.id,`, as in: `id: curr.id,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think visualizing the problem with the images was clearer, but okay...

Anyway I wrote the function below which should be the simplest to understand.

```js
const pets = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Susi' , species: 'dog', gender: 'female'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Mini' , species: 'dog', gender: 'female'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Jojo' , species: 'cat', gender: 'male'},
    {id: 4, name: 'Band' , species: 'cat', gender: 'male'},
    {id: 5, name: 'Tommy' , species: 'rabbit', gender: 'male'}
]

function createNewData(pets){
    // newList that we will be constructing
    const newData = []
    
    //Search in dictionary and get all de Unique Species types
    const speciesList = pets
        .map(({ species }) => species)
        .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
    
    //For each unique species that we found in pets
    for(let i = 0; i < speciesList.length; i++){
        //Inside this loop we will construct each specie object
        
        const specie = speciesList[i]
        const newSpeciesObj = {species: specie, genders: [] }
       
        //The male list will be inside the maleGenderObj
        const maleList = []
        //The female list will be inside the femaleGenderObj
        const femaleList = []

        for(let i = 0; i < pets.length; i++){  
        //Inside this loop we add items to the maleList and femaleList, 
        //if they are of the current specie
            if(pets[i].species == specie) {
                if (pets[i].gender == 'male'){
                    maleList.push(pets[i]) 
                } else {
                    femaleList.push(pets[i])
                }
            }
        }
        //Here we push the maleGenderObject into genders list
        newSpeciesObj.genders.push({gender: 'male', pets: maleList})
        
        //Here we push the femaleGenderObject into genders list
        newSpeciesObj.genders.push({gender: 'female', pets: femaleList})   
        
        //We do this for all the species we found at the original data
        newData.push(newSpeciesObj)    
    }
    
    return newData
}

console.log(createNewData(pets))
```

I'm currently reviewing your code to try to make it work!

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, your explanation make me understand with each line of code.. thanks so much...

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```js
const pets =  [
{id: 1, name: 'Susi', species: 'dog', gender: 'female'},
{id: 2, name: 'Xixi', species: 'dog', gender: 'female'},
{id: 3, name: 'Boss', species: 'rabbit', gender: 'male'}, {id: 4, name: 'Bunny', species: 'rabbit', gender: 'male'}, {id: 5, name: 'kitty', species: 'cat', gender: 'female'},
{id: 6, name: 'Garfield', species: 'cat', gender: 'male'}
]


const data = Object.values(pets.reduce((res, pet) => {
  
  const existingSpecies = res[pet.species] || {species: pet.species, genders:{}}
  
  const existingGender = existingSpecies.genders[pet.gender] || {gender: pet.gender, pets:[]}
  
  return {
    ...res,
    [pet.species]: {
      ...existingSpecies,
      genders: {
        ...existingSpecies.genders,
        [pet.gender]: {
          ...existingGender,
          pets: [...existingGender.pets, pet]
        }
      }
    }
  }

}, {})).map(s => ({...s, genders: Object.values(s.genders)}))

console.log (data)
```